# Strange double import of module in Python

Tags: python, import, module

Running the code provided at https://github.com/Natureshadow/muris reveals a strange kind of behaviour in Python that I do not understand.

The code can be run by placing src/ in the PYTHONPATH and running src/muris/**init**.py.

What happens is that the code in src/muris/**init**.py is executed twice, as if it were included from some other part of the code, but it isn't.

Tracing with the Python trace module also revealed muris.modules.adjektive being imported twice.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python script executed by the interpreter is not loaded into the module system. In the example, the main script is also the top-level **init**.py. This is re-executed when any submodule is imported.

All code that is to be run only on startup has to be surrounded with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```